# AR Object Should not move with AR Camera Vuforia Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am working on Vuforia SDK in that I have one 3d model in AR Camera view.

But when i move my device , 3d model is also moving with that AR Camera view. I want that 3d model should not change its world position until i drag it or move it.

How can i make AR object independent of AR Camera View?

If anyone is having idea then please help me. and i don't want to use any target . i want to float my object in world.

Edit:

Till now i have tried by adding second normal camera with same position and field of view.

then added layer to that AR object and set that layer to the culling mask of the normal camera. AR camera can't see that object. Then also object is moving with camera view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think I might have the solution to this.
Assuming that you're using some target of some sort, select your ARCamera, and view the inspector panel.

Under QCARBehaviour, you'll see  **World Center Mode**

Change that value to **Specific Target** (it should NOT be Camera)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion then also its not working.

Comment: Do you have an image target or any target? Have you done the intial steps properly? Because if it is on Specific target, then it probably isn't finding a target and hence being pushed to camera view.

Comment: Actually i know without image target , its not possible. but i want to float object in world. Vuforia does not support this functionality . So i give up this functionality or else i need to change camera behavior script.

Comment: Thanks for your nice reply.

Comment: If you want it to float then you could possibly use smart terrain prefab. And translate the object in the Y direction so it appears to be floating.

Comment: No no. thats not the way i want to float. you just see "Augment" app on playstore. you might get idea. If my object is in east area then if i move my mobile device then object should be in east area only .

Comment: Oh! Yes, the same can be done with Smart Terrain and extended tracking. Refer this link to give you an idea: https://developer.vuforia.com/library//articles/Training/Extended-Tracking

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions to achieve the output as you want. But...
 
**Very IMP**: What you are trying to do is not an Augmented reality, Its just 3D rendering and you can do the same **without using vuforia not even marker too. you can just use Image processing (OpenCV)**

---

**Solution 1:** select the ARCamera in your Scene, and set the World Center Mode (in the Inspector) to CAMERA (instead of FIRST_TARGET)
[while doing same your child must not be child of ImageTarget]

---

**Solution 2:** Inspect the ImageTargets TrackableBehaviour at runtime, then get the Transform component of it, and extract the position and orientation from that Transform, in World Coordinates (i.e. using Transform.position and Transform.rotation):

You can then set the position and orientation of your Object by deriving it from the one of the Trackable (You have to write custom script for this).

---

But its not an AR in any view because its look somehow like this.
https://youtu.be/iHhMCdh3k7U

 **Correct solution is:**
1 - Select the ImageTarget you have placed in the scene.

2 - In the Inspector, go to the Script component Image Target Behaviour and activate the property: Enable Extended Tracking

Best Luck!